# Undefined parameter when returning data from jQuery.post to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to return data from a database and populate a text field after the user enters an ID in the first text box. Currently I had the code working as long as the user did not enter a space in the ID number. Now I am attempting to allow that use case. My PHP code returns a json encoded array with three fields: first_name, last_name, and full_name.

When I use console.log(data) to view the data being returned I receive the following:

```
    {"first_name":"Test","last_name":"Test","full_name":"Test Test"}
```

However in my code, I try to write *data.full_name* in a .val() nothing is populated, and when use the console.log I get an error saying "undefined".

Here is the whole jQuery Code:

```
    $("#ID").blur(function () {
        var params = {};
        params.ID = encodeURIComponent($(this).val());
        $.post("getter.php", params, function ( data ) {
          if (!data) {
             $("input[name=username]").val("User Not Found");
          } else {
             $("input[name=username]").val(data.full_name);
             $("input[name=username]").attr("readonly", true);
          }
        });
     });
```

Any help you can offer would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force jQuery to read the returned data as json:

```
$("#ID").blur(function () {
        var params = {};
        params.ID = encodeURIComponent($(this).val());
        $.post("getter.php", params, function ( data ) {
          if (!data) {
             $("input[name=username]").val("User Not Found");
          } else {
             $("input[name=username]").val(data.full_name);
             $("input[name=username]").attr("readonly", true);
          }
        }, "json"); // <- json forced
     });
```

and then make sure your returned data is in proper json format (for example with [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) in php)

Comment: By adding JSON to the post, it will send the data to the PHP page as a JSON object, correct? How can I pull that information to run my SQL query on the getter page?

Sorry, that is a new method to me.

Comment: No, it will interpret the data you are getting back as a json object. This is why you are not able to use data.full_name with your above code - jquery is not interpreting the data it receives back as an object. See the jquery documentation on $.post: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ .

Answer (score 0):

Use `trim()` to remove spaces.

Then you can check if the parameter value `is_numeric()`, and if false, set a default value.